# Запятая перед как

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

Все плыло (,) как в тумане.

Прочитала статью на "Грамоте", но не очень поняла, как отличить обстоятельства образа действия от обстоятельств сравнения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли здесь запятая.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все плыло, как в тумане.Я бы поставила запятую, потому что состояния явно сравниваются: всё плыло так, как в тумане.

А вот если бы было"всё было как в тумане" - запятой нет, потому что "как в тумане"входит в сказуемое.

Всё как в тумане - тоже нет запятой.Всё какое? - как в тумане -сказуемое.

Comment: > А вот если бы было"всё было как в тумане" - запятой нет, потому что "как в тумане"входит в сказуемое.

Угу, иными словами, без оборота с союзом "как" сказуемое не имеет законченного смысла

Comment: Спасибо за хорошее объяснение!

Comment: А это не СПП с придаточным сравнительным:"Все плыло, как (все плывет) в тумане" ?

Comment: В неполных придаточных предложения должен быть пропущен только один главный член(подлежащее или сказуемое), например:   Мы втроём начали беседовать, как будто век были знакомы. Гостиная набита гостями, как подушка пером. Дни отрываются от меня, как листики от дерева.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что здесь возможны оба варианта, так как это допускает структура предложения.Оборот с союзом КАК может являться обстоятельством в основном сообщении, но может быть и обособленным обстоятельством.

В то же время в предложении "Всё, как в тумане, плыло у меня перед глазами" оборот обособляется в обязательном порядке, чему способствует его положение между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Примеры необособленных оборотов:   На улице жарко как летом. Глаза её блестели как в лихорадке. Я вроде как на часах при вас нахожусь.Словно белою косынкой подвязалася сосна. Как соломинкой пьёшь мою душу.